# Should I write NSTimer code in view controller or separate class with either delegation/notification pattern?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, nstimer, nsnotificationcenter

I have 5 buttons in my `MotorViewController` that act as on/off switches for 5 motors.  Press button A, motor A will run indefinitely 'til you press the button again to stop it.

I've just added a 6th button that will tell the motor A to run for 2 minutes.  I've added the `NSTimer` code in my `ViewController` and everything works fine.  After 2 minutes, I call my method, `runPump`,  and the motor shuts off automatically.

I've been optimizing my `MotorViewController` quite heavily, and this will be the first time optimizing for an `NSTimer`.

Here's the code:

```
#import "MotorViewController.h"

@interface MotorViewController()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *counterTimer;
@end

@implementation MotorViewController
{
    int _count;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _count = 0;
}

// called from the 6th button action method (code is implied)
- (void)setupTimerForCalib
{
    self.counterTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(timerCount)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.counterTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    NSLog(@"timer started");
}

- (void)timerCount {
    _count++;
    NSLog(@"count: %d", _count);
    if (_count == 120) {
        _count = 0;
        [self.counterTimer invalidate];
        NSLog(@"timer ended");

        // timer has ended, shut pump A (SALINE) off
        [self setPumpInfo:SALINE select:0];
        [self runPump];
    }
}
```

I have another view controller that I'd like to have use these methods, so a better reason yet to not just keep them in `MotorViewController`.

Should I keep these `NSTimer` methods within `MotorViewController`, or create a delegation class for them?  Or (after grazing around on the web a bit), set up an `NSNotification` that, after the 2 minutes, calls `setPumpInfo:select:` and `runPump`?

Whichever the best option, could you also explain the reasoning for that over the other.  I'm trying to learn more about design patterns and know how to use them in the right scenarios.  Thanks!

Comment: you should create timer in each Viewcontroller. And stop timer on navigate from one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have an `NSObject` subclass modelling your pump.
I would give this a `setInfo` and both a `run` and `stop` method (at least).

Your `ViewControllers` should be controlling the views and interacting with your models, so they would create the new pump object (model) that they are interacting with.

Now, you might want to add another method to your `Pump`: `runAfterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay forDuration:(NSTimeInterval) duration` and embed the `NSTimer` within the `Pump` class.

You can then use pumps in your view controllers as follows:

```
-(void) startPump {
    [self.pump setInfo:SALINE select:0];
    [self.pump runAfterDelay: 120 forDuration: 120];
}
```

Keep the logic out of your view controllers, so you don't have to replicate it.

Comment: Excellent idea, ironically enough I have said `Pump` model already in place, but I like your suggestion of adding the timer controls in that model.  All I'm doing in the model so far is creating the `Pump` object with the relevant properties of the pump (speed, direction, etc.).  But I've been manipulating those properties via `MotorViewController`.  But I've a better understanding of what belongs where now, thank you davbryn